# pandas plot time series label the first point on x-axis or change major_ticks

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have a time series plot that starts 2001-01-01 to 2020-12-31. Is there a way I can label the first point in x-axis 2001? Alternatively, can I change the major tick to every 2 years, such that it labels 2001, 2003... 2019?

Sample series:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.rand(240)
ser = pd.Series(data, pd.date_range(start='2001-01-31', end='2020-12-31', freq='M'))
```

[image]

Comment: sure, i just added a sample. Basically it is a pandas series with index in datetime64 format